# Apache + R private repository + Authentication + HTTPS + Install old version

Tags: r, apache, rstudio, cran

My situation is:

- Apache web server on Linux machine
- R local repository (Mirror in /var/www/html/repositories/CRAN)
- Posibility of upload/download personal packages to "private" repositories (/var/www/html/repositories/private1)
- Basic authentication and SSL.
- Need of use old versions of private packages **(PROBLEM HERE)**

I have tried:

`Create /var/www/html/repositories/private1/src/contrib/Archive/pkg1` 
and 
`use devtools::install_version`.

This doesn't work because `gzcon(url(sprintf("%s/src/contrib/Meta/archive.rds", repo), "rb"))` instruction doesn't support HTTP authentication.

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: If you know the old version is there, just use `install.packages("full_path_to_pkg", repos = NULL)`. No need to use devtools at all.

Comment: Yes, I think it is the easiest solution. But if I want to allow private local repositories, and a management tool for developers (upload, download, differentt versions...) I think a local git repository + devtools:install_github is a good solution. What do you think about?